# locate incomplete files that were downloaded with utorrent

Tags: bittorrent

There are a lot of files downloaded with utorrent on one of my hard drives but some of them are incomplete because I interrupted the process of downloading, because I re-installed Windows and now I don't have the torrent files to continue to download them.

Also the incomplete files are not in the same folder and I can't locate them. Is there any way to locate the incomplete files and delete them so not to waste the space of the hard drive?

Comment: "Also the incomplete files are not in the same folder and I can't locate them"? -> The uTorrent configuration contains the folders for 'downloads in progress' and 'completed downloads.' If these are different you know immediately which are incomplete. You can match their file names again the torrent names, this will usually be good enough to determine which belong to which, otherwise you'd have to look in the .torrent file for the downloaded file names.

Comment: Look in C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent for the torrents you added to uTorrent over the years. There is a settings file there that contains where each torrent was downloaded to so it should open each pointing to where you downloaded it to before.

Comment: Seems the settings are only for torrents still listed in uTorrent itself. Still can see what files are each torrent you downloaded over the years by opening them.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to hold it up against, so the only possible solution would be to add the torrents to uTorrent again and target the location the same place as when you downloaded it the first time.
Then uTorrent will check the data on the location with the torrent and you'll see how much their is missing on the perticular torrent.

But you have to do this with each torrent that you have downloaded to that disk.

Comment: the problem is that i don't remember the file names that are incomplete

Comment: is there any other solution in order to determine if they are incomplete and if they are to delete them?

Comment: I'll answer you when i get home later :-)

Comment: ok i'll wait...

Comment: As @Dan D. posted above, then you might have a chance if you tried to look for .part files

Answer (score 0):

A program like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) might be useful.  It gives you a both text and graphical representation of your hard drive.  You might be able to spot the offending files that way.

Another thing, there is an option in uTorrent to append .!incomplete (or something similar to that) to the torrent files as they are downloading.  Then in the future you will always know if a file is incomplete.

Comment: WinDirStat won't help. The incomplete files will most have their full file size allocated and blocks in the file are missing.

Comment: For µTorrent, the extension is `.part`.

Comment: µTorrent uses the extension `.!ut` and that can be enabled with **Append .!ut to incomplete files** in **Preferences > General**.  @DanD. The `.part` extension is used by eMule.